# Clarifying Eq. 101 in The Matrix Cookbook

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace, scalar-fields

Eq. 101 of [The Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) claims that

$$\frac{\partial \operatorname {Tr}(AXB)}{\partial X} = A^\top B^\top$$

The point that is unclear to me is why the dimensions in the product fit? For example, if $A$ is a $2 \times 3$ matrix, $X$ is a $3 \times 5$ matrix and $B$ is a $5 \times 6$ matrix, $A^\top$ is $3 \times 2$ and $B^\top$ is $6 \times 5$, so their product does not seem to make any sense. Am I reading it incorrectly? Is this formula true only for square matrices? If so, what extensions exist for general matrices?

Comment: Trace is only defined for square matrices, so the number of rows in $A$ must match the number of columns in $B$.

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Comment: @angryavian the trace of $A$ is defined for square $A$ but $A$ itself can perfectly be the product of non-square matrices $A = XYZ...$ I believe in formulae like this one needs to interpret "This formula holds every time it makes sense."

Comment: @WillM. What I meant was that (in OP's notation) the product $AXB$ must be square, not that the three matrices $A,X,B$ must be square. OP's example fails because the number of rows of $A$ doesn't match the number of rows of $B$.

Comment: @angryavian yes, that is right! I misread your comment, I thought you wanted all $A,$ $X$ and $B$ square matrixes.

Comment: @WillM. No problem :) I should have been a little clearer in my initial comment.